# How to get rid of double escaping (`&amp;amp;`) when use Maven filters for xml files?

Tags: java, xml, maven, escaping

I use Maven 3 filters to fulfil place holders in xml files. But this requires that the inserted value is (already) xml escaped. What I want is: that Maven take care of escaping the value while putting it in the xml file.

What I have so fare:

Excerpt from the filtered xml file:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/dbConnection"
    url="${it.testDb.jdbc}"
    ...
    />
```

The Propery from the Maven pom:

```
<it.testDb.jdbc>
       jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf8
</it.testDb.jdbc>
```

*You noticed that I have to use `&amp;amp;`. and this is what I want to get rid of, instead I want to write only `&amp;` (the first `&amp;` is because Maven load the parameter from an XML file (pom.xml), thats ok, but the second `amp;` only needed because Maven does not escape the string while writing, and this is what I want to get rid of.)*

**So is there a way that Maven escape the the value to xml-style when it puts the parameter in the file while filtering?**

---

*To be clear: I know that the (first) `&amp;` is needed because the pom is an xml file (like guido suggested in his comment, one can get rid of this by using `<![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8]]>`). But **I am interested in get rid of the second `&amp;` that is needed because the destination file is an xml.** -- Reason: assume I have to write the same value/placeholder in an xml and an txt file, then I would need two different values (one xml escaped and a not escaped one)*

Comment: link to the [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=153108)..it's flag as fixed though..

Comment: It is not a bug in Maven, because Maven does it right (it can not know that I am inserting the value in a xml file). -- Anyway maybe there is a plugin or configuration that instructs Maven to escape this single property <-- this is what the question is about.

Comment: have you tried to put the value within CDATA?

Comment: @guido: you mean on source or destination?

Comment: on source, the property declaration in the pom; being cdata the parser should fetch the text node value as is.

Comment: @guido: that would reduce the first `&amp;` - but I am more interested in removing the second one, because the second one is destination dependend - so when I want to put a placeholder in an xml and an txt file, then I would need to have two different sources.